# UITextfield Value in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a textfield inside a `UITableviewController`. I want to get the user entered data after the user has finished typing and moves to the next field. I want to store that information.

Because once I scroll the user entered data disappears.

Any help is appreciated.

```
if (([indexPath section] == 1) && ([indexPath row] == 2))
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell";

    GeneralInfocell *cell = (GeneralInfocell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GeneralInfocell" owner:self options:nil];

    cell = addresscell;

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;  
    addresscell.txtStreet.delegate = self;

    addresscell.txtStreet.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14];

    addresscell.txtStreet.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    addresscell.txtStreet.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;

    addresscell.txtStreet.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    addresscell.txtStreet.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    addresscell. txtStreet.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    addresscell. txtStreet.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

    addresscell.txtStreet.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [addresscell.txtStreet addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidEndEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
}
```

In the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method I have,

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    UILabel *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[addresscell.txtCity text]];
    NSLog(@"label:%@",label);

}
```

But I don't get any value.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't `[addresscell.txtStreet addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidEndEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];` redundant as the delegate method should be called right?

Comment: I removed it. Still It didnt work...could you please give any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UITextFieldDelegate` should be something like this –

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    NSLog(@"Data entered: %@", textField.text);
}
```

Since everything else is wired correctly, you should get a proper value now.

Since cells are reused, you lose data on scrolling. You will need to reset the text field's value every time the cell is requested. For this, you can maintain a mutable array of strings if there are multiple fields, one for each of the text fields. When a text field is dismissed, save the data entered in the array and restore it next time the cell is requested for.

Let me know if you need any further assistance.

**EDIT**
`tag` all the ten text fields 0 to 9.

Declare a NSMutableArray iVar in your view controller, say `data`, to store the strings for the text fields.

In `-viewDidLoad:`,

```
...
data = [[NSMutableArray] initWithCapacity:10];
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    [data addObject:@""];
}
...
```

In `-textFieldDidEndEditing:`,

```
...
[data replaceObjectAtIndex:[textField tag] withObject:[textField text]];
...
```

In `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`,

```
...
// Since they are named variables, it will be something on lines of 
addressCell.txtStreet.text = [data objectAtIndex:[addressCell.txtStreet tag]];
// Repeat for all other text fields
...
```

Don't forget to release `data` in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: I tried like below. I get only label: in the log. No value in it.      - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    
    if([textField viewWithTag:kViewTag]){
    
    UILabel *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[addresscell.txtStreet text]];
        
        NSLog(@"label:%@",label);
    }

Comment: i have more than 10 fields inside custom UITableviewcell. could be please show me a simple example how to add the value to array. I used ur code and in data entered i was able to see the data entered. After that what should i do. thank u so much

Comment: Assuming there are 10 name text fields inside a single cell, I have posted the code in my answer under EDIT. Check it out.

Comment: Thank u so much. I am trying to use the method u mentioned.Will update once i finish it.

Comment: I need another help. If I wanted to maintain the state of the UISwitch in the scroll like the UITExtfield data, How can i achieve it. Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: say if you need to save states of more than a single control, its better to package that information in a class and then save instances of that class in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method.

Comment: I have implemented it and please find my code below. still it didnt work.

Comment: Thank u so much for the reply.Please see my code in the EDIT. in the textFieldDidEndEditing:i have done it.